# reload html content each time tab selected in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using tabset (AngularUI)

```
  <tabset justified="true">
    <tab heading="Justified">my html content</tab>
    <tab heading="SJ">Short Labeled Justified content</tab>
    <tab heading="Long Justified">Long Labeled Justified content</tab>
  </tabset>
```

my html content is dynamic data that I am loading from database, this page is editable and have save button. If I am editing the data and don't press on the save button and than I am going to another tab and back to my tab I don't want to see the edited data, I want to see the loaded data again, till I am pressing "Save". that means that I need to load all my data and page each time I select tab (start the controller). What is the best and correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define for each tab the `select` attribute, which can call a function on your scope. Here's the [relevant part from the docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs):

> `select()` (Defaults: null) : An optional expression called when tab is activated.

And part from their example:

```
 <tab select="alertMe()">
```

Comment: so, the correct thing to do here is to call the function in my controller that loads my page again? I tried to do this, but the problem is that the validators from my last visit in this page keep to show(I have form validation that show green/red on my inputs)

Comment: Yep, load and update the displayed content in the relevant tab (probably a scope var).

Comment: I see....Is there a fast and good way to reset my html5 validators? they keep displaying on my page even after uploading the data again. thank you very much

Comment: You mean angular's form validation ? If so, try to set the form to a pristine mode, see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine